# No able to redirect to home page with React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

When the user is clicking on the `EDIT` icon one page will be opened. After the user `submit` the record, and if it is successful, our page should come to redirect to the `ListCertificate`.

The below line will run when the user clicks on the edit button. And the edit form will be opened.

```
<Link to={`/${props.certificate.id}/edit` }>Edit</Link>
```

After the user saves successfully, our page should redirect to the `ListCertificate` component.

So I am writing it

```
 .then(function (response: any) {
      console.log(response);
      toast(" Record updated successflly", {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined
      });
       return <Redirect  to='/listcertificate'  />
    })
```

this line is not working.

```
return <Redirect  to='/listcertificate'  />
```

In app.js, I have called ListCertificate using the below.

```
<Route  path ="/listcertificate" component={Listcertificate} ></Route>
```

`localhost:4200/listcertificate` is working properly. But it is not getting redirected to the same page from editcomponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `react-router-dom` v6, you can use `useNavigate` hook for navigate programmatically. [Docs](http://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
..
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
.then(function (response: any) {
      console.log(response);
      toast(" Record updated successflly", {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined
      });
       navigate("/listcertificate", { replace: true });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `useHistory` instead of `Redirect` when you are not in `JSX` :

```js
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

const history = useHistory();
history.push('/listcertificate');
```

And if you are using React Router Dom `v6`, use `useNavigate`:

```js
 import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
 
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 
 navigate("/listcertificate", { replace: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `replace` prop inside `<Navigate/>`.

*The `<Navigate replace>` prop tells the router to use `history.replaceState()` when updating the URL so the / entry won't end up in the history stack. This means that when someone clicks the back button, they'll end up at the page they were at before they navigated to `/`* [read more](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/b5748add2795ce7448a366ae8f8ae3bb)

##### Change this

`<Redirect to='/listcertificate'  />`

##### To this

`<Navigate to='/listcertificate' replace  />`

**or to this**

`<Navigate to='/listcertificate' replace={true}  />`

Comment: A `<Navigate>` element changes the current location when it is rendered in JSX but @Niharika Suse call redirect in function callback outside JSX.

Comment: There is no `Redirect` component in RRDv6, and it also doesn't have a `replace` prop, but using the `Navigate` component which replaced it would still have the same issue. OP needs an imperative navigation, not a declarative one.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for mentioning my mistake, I updated my answer